# putting static folder under a virtual directory

Tags: express

following is the usual way to make a static folder available to html:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

so in the html, it can be refered as:

```
<link href="/stylesheets/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I'd like to do it another way:

```
<link href="/myfolder/stylesheets/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

myfolder does not exist, I just want to put public under myfolder, possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is simple in express.

The `app.use` method takes a 'mount' point as its first parameter.  This is the URL where any middleware will mount.

So in your case, it would look like this:

```
app.use('/myfolder', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

This is [in the docs](http://expressjs.com/api.html#express.static). ;-)